# Ubuntu does not recognize VGA and display hardware

Tags: display, display-resolution

I currently installed Ubuntu 20 and I encountered a problem that **it does not recognize VGA display hardware** also my resolution is very low. How should I get a driver or solve this issue? Any idea?

Comment: What is Ubuntu 20? What is the hardware?

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu has both *yy* releases (eg. Ubuntu Core 20) and *yy.mm* releases (eg. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server/Desktop), and they are different products. There is no Ubuntu 20, closest being Ubuntu Core 20, which is a less powerful product than the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server/Desktop, but that's also it's advantage (it's smaller thus ideal for appliances/devices/cloud/VMs etc).  Ubuntu Core 20 is usually used headless.